# htaccess to redirect root to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

We have a GoDaddy hosting. Within public_html we have a number of folders, each for a different site.

The main site (mysite.com) should normally be in the public_html but we moved them to public_html/mysite. We had an htaccess file to handle this change.

mysite.com is a slim (PHP) site. Within its public folder is another htaccess file that redirects to the public subfolder.

We tried to redirect mysite to a different web address and something got broken. Now if I go to mysite.com it shows Forbidden. Also, the FTP no longer works. When I try to connect with Filezilla I get

```
    Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".
```

This is because I try to connect to ftp.mysite.com. If I change that to an IP it does work. But clearly something is off with mysite.com.

The current htaccess within public_html/mysite is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!public)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas on how can I get this to work again? I think the problem is that the domain is pointing to the root of the public_html folder instead of public_html/mysite but no idea how to fix this.

**UPDATE**

We have an htaccess file in the public_html folder

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!mysite)(.*)$ /mysite/$1 [L]
```

If I remove it, all subdomains work but mysite.com shows Forbidden. If I enable the file, then every single subdomain, including mysite.com shows Internal Server Error.

Comment: Try commenting out `RewriteOptions inherit`

Comment: @anubhava This worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have this .htaccess in site root:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!mysite/)(.*)$ mysite/$1 [L,NC]
```

You should remove `RewriteOptions inherit` directive as that is not serving any purpose here.

Also note some minor fixes in your rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks you sir for sharing nice code. Could you please do let me know if any other htaccess is not present(that inherit option) and we are using it; so will it cause issues?

Comment: This rule should never be inherited in sub directory .htaccess because it is routing all requests to `mysite/` folder and that won't be available in another sub directory.